# Terraform does not update aws_ecs_service when registry image is updated and service applied again

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a Terraform-provisioned ECS cluster, backed by EC2 instances. I'm deploying a custom Wiremock container. If I change the mappings in the container, build and push to the registry, I can see that after attempting to push layers that already exist, it pushes up the last layer:

```
4c6899b75fdb: Layer already exists
cc9a6810e763: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:1366cd467087b33e3ea3e159adf92ee9d11b53af87911c5563ee028aecbea8d4 size: 1366
```

However, when I try to apply that image to the service using this Terraform file:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "wiremock" {
    family                = "wiremock"
    tags                  = "${var.default_tags}"
    volume {
      name = "wiremock_logs"
      host_path = "/var/log/wiremock/"
    }
    requires_compatibilities = ["EC2"]
    container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
[
  {
    "name": "wiremock",
    "image": "${var.ecr_url}/${var.repository_name}:${var.tag}",
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 8080,
        "hostPort": 80
      }
    ],
    "mountPoints": [
      {
        "sourceVolume" : "wiremock_logs",
        "containerPath" : "/var/log/wiremock/"
      }
    ],
    "memory": 500,
    "cpu": 10
  }
]
DEFINITION
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "wiremock" {
    name            = "wiremock"
    cluster         = "${data.aws_ecs_cluster.thelma_cluster.id}"
    task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.wiremock.family}:${max("${aws_ecs_task_definition.wiremock.revision}", "${aws_ecs_task_definition.wiremock.revision}")}"
    desired_count   = "${var.desired_count}"
}
```

The result is this:

`Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.`

How do I force Terraform or AWS to check the image registry for updates (a new hash)? It seems to be checking only for a new task definition, which is unchanged by a new image upload.

Comment: I do not see a Launch Configuration anywhere in that config, but the root cause behind this is probably that you are specifying the image tag as "latest" each time you rebuild the image, so it has no delta in your config.

Comment: There wouldn't be a Launch Configuration, since these are container services. The corollary is the task definition in the aws_ecs_service resource.

Comment: Your comment about `latest` makes sense, though. I'm optimizing for ease of use and minimizing parameters, but the output of the build step is necessarily input for the deploy step, so a common tag seemed appropriate. I'll investigate other patterns for tagging.

Comment: Edited the original post to remove confusing reference to Launch Config.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, and also switched from a unique tag to latest to minimize ease because I couldn't figure out how to pass the tag from the build step to the deploy step. I just noticed though in my deploy step that I'm never referencing the tag anyways, just the image. I'm going to experiment and see if it will still update the ESC task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*" If your updated Docker image uses the same tag as what is in the existing task definition for your service (for example, my_image:latest), you do not need to create a new revision of your task definition. You can update the service using the procedure below, keep the current settings for your service, and select Force new deployment. The new tasks launched by the deployment pull the current image/tag combination from your repository when they start. The Force new deployment option is also used when updating a Fargate task to use a more current platform version when you specify LATEST. For example, if you specified LATEST and your running tasks are using the 1.0.0 platform version and you want them to relaunch using a newer platform version."*

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/update-service.html

**TLDR;
Force an update of the tasks via cli or stop/start them from the webconsole.**

If not using fargate then might not work depending on the settings being used by  ECS Agent (if the instance already has a copy might not check for a new one). Configure the pull behaviour of ECS Agent via env variables.

ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR=always

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html

Comment: Unfortunately, while this appeared to be the desired setting, it does not affect the actual behavior of Terraform. I will have to come up with a more robust tagging process to ensure that new task definitions are being created.

Comment: This solution does not use/require terraform. 
After uploading your new images to ecr run service update.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html

Comment: I had hoped that using that ECS variable would change the behavior of TF. I see your point though, and I see no reason to stubbornly hold to using this tool (it's all wrapped in Jenkins jobs, anyway). Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 13):

You can include the ECR image digest in your ECS JSON config. In order to obtain the digest, you would first create a ECR image data source in the Terraform:

```
data "aws_ecr_image" "wiremock" {
  repository_name = "${var.repository_name}"
  image_tag = "${var.tag}"
}
```

You can then reference it in your JSON as follows:

```
"image": "${var.ecr_url}/${var.repository_name}:${var.tag}@${data.aws_ecr_image.wiremock.image_digest}",
```

This will cause Terraform to recreate the task definition and update the service each time your image changes.

Comment: Thanks @trogDor, I was looking how to force terraform to create a new task each time, and with your solution worked like a charm.

Comment: what is `var.tag` in `image_tag = "${var.tag}"`? should that be explicitly declared as a variable in `variables.tf` file?

Comment: @AllaSasikanth it represents the Docker image tag (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/). The OP was already referencing a variable called `${var.tag}` in the terraform example they provided.

Comment: I am having issues on destroy and cannot do apply for the first time. Data causes an issue as for the first time apply there is no image_digest to fetch.

Any opinions how to solve that?

Comment: @ÖzgürAtmaca that sounds odd. The `aws_ecr_image` resource should be querying your ECR image registry. I would recommend creating a new question with more details about your set up.

Answer (score 5):

As others said, terraform is hard to detect the change when docker image tag is always `latest`.

You can update code as below:

prepare the task definition template

```
$ cat task_definition.tpl

[
  {
    "name": "wiremock",
    "image": "${ecr_url}/${repository_name}:${var.tag}",
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 8080,
        "hostPort": 80
      }
    ],
    "mountPoints": [
      {
        "sourceVolume" : "wiremock_logs",
        "containerPath" : "/var/log/wiremock/"
      }
    ],
    "memory": 500,
    "cpu": 10
  }
]
```

then update terraform files

```
data "template_file" "task_definition" {
  template = "${file("${"${path.module}/task_definition.tpl"}")}"

  vars {
    ecr_url             = "${var.ecr_url}"
    var.repository_name = "${var.repository_name}"
    tag                 = "${var.tag}"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "wiremock" {
    family                = "wiremock"
    tags                  = "${var.default_tags}"
    volume {
      name = "wiremock_logs"
      host_path = "/var/log/wiremock/"
    }
    requires_compatibilities = ["EC2"]
    container_definitions = "${data.template_file.task_definition.rendered}"
    ...
}
```

When apply the change, use the new tag which applied to docker image, normally I applied build number within tag name, such as `1.0.<build_number>` when build the docker image.

```
TF_VAR_tag=1.0.${BUILD_NUMBER} terraform apply
```

With this way, terraform will detect the change (docker image tag is keep changed with build number).